# Instagram story scraper didn't work with curl or file_get_contents method in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, instagram

I'm trying to fetch the **story** `json` data of **instagram public account** using curl or `file_get_contents` methods but unfortunately got no luck so far. As I figure, I cannot fetch the json data from the instagram url. Somehow instagram doesn't allow me to get the story data.

**FOR TEST**

User ID: 22009575863

We can access the **test url** directly: https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17873473675158481&variables=%7B%22precomposed_overlay%22%3Afalse%2C%22reel_ids%22%3A22009575863%7D

But cannot get the file contents(json) using curl method and this is my problem.
Somehow `getContents($url, $cookies = true)` not return any story data but accessing the url directly return successful.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label><?php language('_PLACEHOLDER2'); ?></label>
    <input type="url" id="input" name="input" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php language('_PLACEHOLDER2'); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="story">
    <input type="hidden" name="json" id="json" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>">
    <button id="btnDownloadStory" class="btn btn-default btn-block mt-3">
       <i class="fas fa-download"></i> <?php language('_DOWNLOAD'); ?>
     </button>
</div>
```

**HTML OUTPUT:**
[image: HERE]

**POST**
[image: HERE]

**PHP**
USING SWITCH CASE

```
switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'story':
            if (isset($json['graphql']['user']['username']) != '') {
                $data['user'] = $instagram->getProfileFromData($json['graphql']['user']);
            } else {
                $data['user'] = $instagram->getProfile($username, true);
            }
            $data['medias'] = $instagram->getStories($data['user']['id']);
            break;
     
        default:
            returnError('Invalid action.');
            break;
    }


 /**
 * @param int $userId
 * @return array
 */
public function getStories($userId)
{
  
    $baseUrl = 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17873473675158481&variables=';

    $variables = '{"precomposed_overlay":false,"reel_ids":["' . $userId . '"]}';
    $stories = $this->getContents($baseUrl . urlencode($variables), true);
    $data = json_decode($stories, true);
    if (isset($data['data']['reels_media'][0]['items']) == '') {
        return array();
    }
    $stories = $data['data']['reels_media'][0]['items'];
    $medias = array();
    foreach ($stories as $story) {
        switch ($story['__typename']) {
            case 'GraphStoryImage':
                $i = count($story['display_resources']) - 1;
                array_push($medias, array(
                    'type' => 'image',
                    'fileType' => 'jpg',
                    'url' => $story['display_resources'][$i]['src'],
                    'downloadUrl' => $story['display_resources'][$i]['src'] . '&dl=1'
                ));
                break;
            case 'GraphStoryVideo':
                $i = count($story['video_resources']) - 1;
                array_push($medias, array(
                    'type' => 'video',
                    'fileType' => 'mp4',
                    'preview' => $story['display_url'],
                    'url' => $story['video_resources'][$i]['src'],
                    'downloadUrl' => $story['video_resources'][$i]['src'] . '&dl=1'
                ));
                break;
        }
    }
    return $medias;
}
```

**Instragram.php**

```
$cookieFile = __DIR__ . '/../storage/cookie.txt';

$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'; 

/**
 * @param string $url
 * @param bool $cookies
 * @return string
 */
public function getContents($url, $cookies = true)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Cookie ' . file_get_contents($this->cookieFile)
    ));
  
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data; //return empty here
}
```

Comment: When you try it in your browser you have all the cookies of IG authentication. I see that on your `Instragram.php` you have set the CookieFile but have you also imported the cookies from your browser or have you generated the necessary cookies somehow? Otherwise you don't have any cookies and Instagram stops you.

Comment: I check that...cookie.txt file was empty in first place

Comment: So, since cookie.txt is empty, you don't have any cookies and Instagram blocks you because you don't have any permissions to access the stories. Only logged in users can access the stories and your CURL is simulating a logged-off user.

Comment: yes, i guess this causing the issue